# Powershell Format-Table with new line break adds extra space between column

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-5.0

I've got 2 Scheduled Tasks in Windows: StartAppPool and StopAppPool.

In StartAppPool I've got only 1 job trigger. In StopAppPool I've got 2 job triggers.

I'm trying to create a script that can display the status of my Scheduled Tasks and related properties.

```
Write-Host "9. Checking Task Scheduler Execution Status...." -BackgroundColor DarkCyan
$taskService = New-Object -ComObject "Schedule.Service"
$taskService.Connect($env:COMPUTERNAME)
$rootTaskFolder = $taskService.GetFolder('\')
$tasks = $rootTaskFolder.GetTasks(1) | Where-Object { $_.Name -in 'StopAppPool','StartAppPool' }

$TaskArray = @()
ForEach ( $task in $tasks ) {
    $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $object | Add-Member -Name 'Name' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $task.Name
    $object | Add-Member -Name 'TaskEnabled' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $task.Enabled
    $object | Add-Member -Name 'LastRunTime' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $task.LastRunTime
    $object | Add-Member -Name 'NextRunTime' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $task.NextRunTime

    $TaskXMLObject = [xml]$task.Xml
    $CalendarTriggers = $TaskXMLObject.Task.Triggers.CalendarTrigger


    $TaskTriggerArray = @()
    ForEach ($CalendarTrigger in $CalendarTriggers) {
        $object2 = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        $object2 | Add-Member -Name 'StartBoundary' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value ( Get-Date $CalendarTrigger.StartBoundary.Replace('T',' ') -Format "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" )
        $object2 | Add-Member -Name 'Enabled' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $CalendarTrigger.Enabled
        $DaysOfWeek = ( $CalendarTrigger.ScheduleByWeek.DaysOfWeek | Get-Member -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name) | ForEach-Object -Process { [enum]::parse([System.DayOfWeek],$_ ) } | Sort-Object #parsing the values into an enum will allow the objects to be sorted by day instead of alphabetical order           
        $object2 | Add-Member -Name 'DaysOfWeek' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value ( $DaysOfWeek -join ', ' )

        $TaskTriggerArray += $object2
    }

    $object | Add-Member -Name 'StartBoundary' -MemberType NoteProperty -Value ($TaskTriggerArray.StartBoundary | Out-String )
    $object | Add-Member -Name 'TriggerEnabled' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value ($TaskTriggerArray.Enabled | Out-String )
    $object | Add-Member -Name 'DaysOfWeek' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value ($TaskTriggerArray.DaysOfWeek | Out-String )
    $TaskArray += $object

}

$TaskArray | Format-Table Name, TaskEnabled, LastRunTime, NextRunTime, @{Label='StartBoundary';Expression={(($_.StartBoundary )}}, TriggerEnabled, DaysOfWeek -Wrap
```

Unfortunately, the "StartBoundary" column seems to append extra spaces behind and I couldn't figure how how to fix that. Here's the sample output

```
Name         TaskEnabled LastRunTime          NextRunTime          StartBoundary                                    TriggerEnabled DaysOfWeek                                                
----         ----------- -----------          -----------          -------------                                    -------------- ----------                                                
StartAppPool        True 10/2/2017 6:00:00 AM 11/2/2017 6:00:00 AM 29/09/2016 06:00:00 AM                           true           Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday    

StopAppPool         True 10/2/2017 5:10:01 AM 11/2/2017 5:10:00 AM 29/09/2016 05:10:00 AM                           true           Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday            
                                                                   05/11/2016 10:00:00 AM                           true           Saturday
```

Anyone has an idea how I can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Trim** method, like this:

```
$_.StartBoundary.ToString().Trim()
```

You can also try to add **-AutoSize** switch for **Format-Table** cmdlet

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. do you see the space get trimmed if you could try that out on your side?

Comment: @louisxie, sorry but I don't really see any extra spacings. Why do you actually using advanced formatting? The property seems to be the same. You may try to use extra Width formatting. Like this @{Label='StartBoundary';Expression={$_.StartBoundary};Width=10;Align='Center'} or basically just add -AutoSize switch.